# Docker losing Postgres server data when I shutdown the backend container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I've got the following docker-compose file and it serves up the application on port 80 fine.

```
version: '3'

services:
    backend:
        build: ./Django-Backend
        command: gunicorn testing.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --log-level debug
        expose:
            - "8000"
        volumes:
            - static:/code/backend/static
        env_file:
            - ./.env.prod

    nginx:
        build: ./nginx
        ports:
            - 80:80
        volumes:
            - static:/static
        depends_on:
            - backend

    db:
        image: postgres
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
        volumes:
            - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

volumes:
    static:
    postgres_data:
```

Once in there I can log into the admin and add an extra user which gets saved to the database as I can reload the page and the user is still there. Once I stop the backend docker container however that user is gone. Given Postgres is operating in a different container and I'm not bringing it down I'm unsure how stopping the backend container and restarting it is causing the data not to be available.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I'm bringing up the docker container with the following command.

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d
```

I'm bringing down the container by just using docker desktop and stopping the container.

I'm running DJANGO 3 for the backend and I've also tried adding a superuser in the terminal when the container is running:

```
# python manage.py createsuperuser 
Username (leave blank to use 'root'): mikey
Email address: 
Password: 
Password (again): 
This password is too common.
Bypass password validation and create user anyway? [y/N]: y
Superuser created successfully.
```

Which works and the user appears while the container is running. However, once again when I shut the container down via docker desktop and then restart it that user that was just created is gone.

FURTHER EDIT:

settings.py using dotenv "from dotenv import load_dotenv"

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": os.getenv("SQL_ENGINE"),
        "NAME": os.getenv("SQL_DATABASE"),
        "USER": os.getenv("SQL_USER"),
        "PASSWORD": os.getenv("SQL_PASSWORD"),
        "HOST": os.getenv("SQL_HOST"),
        "PORT": os.getenv("SQL_PORT"),
    }
}
```

with the .env.prod file having the following values:

```
DEBUG=0
DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost 127.0.0.1 [::1]
SQL_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
SQL_DATABASE=postgres
SQL_USER=postgres
SQL_PASSWORD=postgres
SQL_HOST=db
SQL_PORT=5432
```

SOLUTION:

Read the comments to see the diagnosis by other legends but updated docker-compose file looks like this. Note the "depends_on" block.

```
version: '3'

services:
    backend:
        build: ./Django-Backend
        command: gunicorn testing.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --log-level debug
        expose:
            - "8000"
        volumes:
            - static:/code/backend/static
        env_file:
            - ./.env.prod
        depends_on:
            - db

    nginx:
        build: ./nginx
        ports:
            - 80:80
        volumes:
            - static:/static
        depends_on:
            - backend

    db:
        image: postgres
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
        volumes:
            - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        expose:
            - "5432"

volumes:
    static:
    postgres_data:
```

FINAL EDIT:

Added the following code to my entrypoint.sh file to ensure Postgres is ready to accept connections by the backend container.

```
if [ "$DATABASE" = "postgres" ]
then
    echo "Waiting for postgres..."

    while ! nc -z $SQL_HOST $SQL_PORT; do
      sleep 0.1
    done

    echo "PostgreSQL started"
fi
```

Comment: Could you please add the command you use to bring down the backend container? generally, give us a bit more info on the exact process you follow

Comment: No worries added more detail. Hope that helps

Comment: How are you connecting to database in `settings.py`? Is it being connected to `postgres` itself or is it using the default `sqlite3` db?

Comment: Added a further edit to help out. It's using Postgres database via .env.prod file.

Comment: Can you expose postgres port from `db` container and map it to some port of the host machine. Then connect to the database using pgAdmin or postico app if you are in mac and verify that indeed the data is created. I am skeptical because in docker compose file, `backend` does not have `depends_on`  block and django might be falling back to `sqlite3`

Comment: @MjZac You sir are a legend! I didn't bother going through the pgAdmin as soon as you said the "depends_on" block my mind clicked and realised that it was missing and that was likely causing the weird behaviour. You were correct, as soon as I added the "depends on" it retained the data after shutdown and all the data was there on restart. Thanks again legend. That would have taken me hours to solve.

Comment: Glad to be of help :) Though I would give you another warning that `depends_on` just make sure the `db` container will be up before `backend`. There is a pretty good chance that postgres won't have started accepting connections. Take a look at this answer to make sure postgres is accepting connections before starting the django container. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60739093/2861108

Comment: @MjZac Thanks, I'll add the following code to the entrypoint code to make sure Postgres is ready to rock.

if [ "$DATABASE" = "postgres" ]
then
    echo "Waiting for postgres..."

    while ! nc -z $SQL_HOST $SQL_PORT; do
      sleep 0.1
    done

    echo "PostgreSQL started"
fi